# how to use collect-view in Cooja in my own application

Tags: contiki

i have a question about collect-view. Can collect-view be used in other applications? i simulate some applications by cooja, and want to collect information about network,such as network map,ETX and so on. how can i use collect-view to collect information about my own applications?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `apps/collect-view` or in your application you can add your own information to be sent by collect by redefining `collect_view_arch_read_sensors`, check for example how it is done for the Z1 mote in the `collect-view-z1.c`:

```
#include "collect-view.h"
#include "cc2420.h"
#include "dev/leds.h"
#include "dev/i2cmaster.h"
#include "dev/tmp102.h"

#include "collect-view-z1.h"

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static uint16_t
get_temp()
{
  /* XXX Fix me: check /examples/z1/test-tmp102.c for correct conversion */
  return (uint16_t)tmp102_read_temp_raw();
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void
collect_view_arch_read_sensors(struct collect_view_data_msg *msg)
{
  static int initialized = 0;

  if(!initialized) {
    tmp102_init();
    initialized = 1;
  }

  msg->sensors[BATTERY_VOLTAGE_SENSOR] = 0;
  msg->sensors[BATTERY_INDICATOR] = 0;
  msg->sensors[LIGHT1_SENSOR] = 0;
  msg->sensors[LIGHT2_SENSOR] = 0;
  msg->sensors[TEMP_SENSOR] = get_temp();
  msg->sensors[HUMIDITY_SENSOR] = 0;
}
```

Notice that `collect_view_arch_read_sensors(msg);` is called by `collect-view.c` when you call `collect_view_construct_message(...)` from your application.  This is how it is done in the [examples/ipv6/rpl-collect/udp-sender.c](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/ipv6/rpl-collect/udp-sender.c) example:

```
/* Collect structure */
struct {
    uint8_t seqno;
    uint8_t for_alignment;
    struct collect_view_data_msg msg;
  } msg;

/* Create the collect structure */
collect_view_construct_message(&msg.msg, &parent,
                               parent_etx, rtmetric,
                               num_neighbors, beacon_interval);

/* Send over UDP */
uip_udp_packet_sendto(client_conn, &msg, sizeof(msg),
                      &server_ipaddr, UIP_HTONS(UDP_SERVER_PORT));
```

Comment: thanks for your comments! 
About `sender.c sink.c` and `collect-view.c`, I have read them. Now, I have two questions:first, how does `collect_view_construct_message(...)` deliver those information to collect-view and then show in Collect-View GUI?
second, in `sender.c`, we can see `collect_common_send()` redefined. But in `sink.c`, there is no code in this function. So I do not how does sink to deal with received information.

`void
collect_common_send(void)
{
  /* Server never sends */
}`
Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

When contiki calls the Call back function, for example the *recv()* function in rime-protocol, The sink node should use *printf()* to print out the sensor data. This output then will be read by Collect View GUI per-line.

take a look at 
[tools/collect-view/src/org/contikios/contiki/collect/CollectServer.java](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/tools/collect-view/src/org/contikios/contiki/collect/CollectServer.java)

The *handleIncomingData()* called by *serialData()*, then checks if it's a sensor data or not in *SensorData.parseSensorData()*.
It will ignore if empty, incorrect format, comment, or annotation

sensor data will be displayed in Collect View GUI if meets some condition. for example, the data length calculated match with datalen implisit on its sensor data.